# How should I proceed with NLP to extract information from tables?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I'm used to using NLP with sentences extracted from pdf's but right now I have to work with data located in tables and as you probably it's much more bothersome... I have no issue locating the pagse in which the tables I want are located that's just classification, the issue is extracting the tables and processing them.

Right now, I think I'm facing two choices and I wonder which would be the best :

1. Using OCR to extract the tables, I have had some success with this but I would need to train a custom model for this, but the real issue is that I don't know how to parse a table like this. The result would be a dataframe, I don't know how I would proceed in order to locate the specific information I want in that dataframe.
2. Extract the table in text format, I've made some tries and the resulting set would be a list of strings with a string equal to one row (columns are separated by spaces), with that I could make a custom NER and extract the information I want.

If anyone faced the same issue, how did you proceed ? I'm open to any idea.

Thank's.